# How can I use a measure in calculated column in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I calculate a quartile in a measure :

```
 Percentile1_25 = CALCULATE(PERCENTILEX.EXC(DWH;DWH[AREA];0,25);DWH[TYPE_APPART] = "1")
```

that I want to use in a calculated column :

```
 COL= if(DWH[TYPE_APPART] = "1"; if(DWH[AREA]>[Percentile1_75];"a";"b");"c")
```

but I have this error :

```
 "The value of the percentile must be in the range 1 / (N + 1) .. N / (N + 1) included, where N is the number of data values."
```

Does someone know this error ?

If I put the real value of Percentile1_75 it's ok, but the measure is not accepted.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculated column is not returning expected result because the measure and the calculated column has a different row context. You may try to combine both formula into one to avoid such behavior:

i.e.

```
column = 
VAR measure = measure formula
RETURN column formula
```

e.g.

```
COL =
VAR Percentile1_25 = CALCULATE(PERCENTILEX.EXC(DWH;DWH[AREA];0,25);DWH[TYPE_APPART] = "1")
RETURN if(DWH[TYPE_APPART] = "1"; if(DWH[AREA]>Percentile1_25;"a";"b");"c")
```

Comment: It doesn't work, VALUES is for table or column, not for mesure apparently. It's the same problem for FIRSTNOTBLANK, it's for column also. In my case, Percentile1_75 = 35 for example. But thank you for help :)

Comment: @MarieT Sorry I've mixed up the question the other way round "How to use a calculated column in a measure". Let's see if the amended solution helps, or you can provide some sample data for better understanding if not :)

Comment: @MarieT Glad to help :)